# Assign a domain name to a static IP

Tags: apache, url, dns, apache2, ip

OS: Debian stable

Server: Apache2/webdav

Router: Plusnet technicolor tg82n

IP: static

---

I am in the early stages with my learning on this.
I set up a apache2 server and webdav, i also had my isp assign a static IP. The idea is for me to be able to access my files over the internet and allow family to get access too.

So far so good, the servers work. The issue is i want something other than an IP to pass to family members. I am very new to this, i only set up apache2/webdav and made the html pages yesterday, so my head is a bit over loaded.

I registered a free domain with freenom today, to redirect to my servers static ip. I assumed that it would just redirect, but it doesn't. It had a section in there for dns to be entered so i looked on my router and entered them into freenom and they where not accepted. I then selected the freenom supplied dns and noticed it asked for some settings (which have no instruction) and got confused. Obviously i have no idea what i am doing at this point.

So, i am hoping to get some help from people who know what they are doing.

- Do i need to change something in my apache2 config?
- Do i need to enter something into my router?
- Do i need to do more than just set up a redirect with freenom (aka these dns settings)?

Should i be using something better than freenom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your family enters the domain you registered into their browser, lets call your domain `family.org` the pattern is:

- Browser looks at nearest DNS server to find the ipaddress of the server which is hosting the files/resources for `family.org`

Say the ip adddress of the server is `217.1.63.128` once properly configured your DNS server will be set:

`family.org` >> `217.1.63.128`

You need to configure this manually - your DNS provider or ISPs, likely wont have done this.

You need to set your `a record` in DNS config i.e.

`family.org.` > `a record` > `217.1.63.128`   - NOTE : you have to have the dot suffix on `family.org.`

This can take up to 24hrs for the DNS config to resolve - it depends on what the TTL setting are set to - so expect to have to wait a up to day.

If your files are hosted in the root level directory of your apache server you wont need to configure a virtual host - just forward a port from your routers firewall to the server.

You can check this config before DNS resolves by pointing your browser to the "live" static ip they assigned you. i.e. type in `http://217.1.63.128` or whatever your ip address is into your browser.

Your files should be served, if not you need to configure port forwarding

Comment: I have now set the dns as: mydomain.cf. > a record > mystaticip 

The TTL is 14440, that was the standard, does that sound right for a TTL?  

My 'greeting page' that i want to redirect to is set as the root level apache directory [/var/www/webpagename] in the 'sites-available' file. I have forwarded the correct ports from the router for http and https already and i can get access to the apache2/webdav server via my staticIP through a web browser (a friend also tested outside of my home network and gained access) so that part is sorted.

Cheers!

Comment: If that is working for you great - but I suspect you may have broken the apache config. Sites-available is not for the files you want to serve - it is a configuration file for apache virrtual hosts - I would recommend against modifying that file - as you can break the install - and it will be difficult to recover unless you tracked exactly what you changed.

Comment: Oh, i followed instruction from a guide. i will look into that. which file should i have altered? Also, in fact, i thought 'mydomain.cf. had set, but it came up with a blank name field after i created it. Freenom has the fields 'name' type' 'ttl' 'target'. If i enter 'mydomain' in the name field it saves, but not with the .cf. extension, it keeps turning blank.

Comment: if you change these files you should always make a copy of the original so you can recover in case you set it wrong. web directory for files on apache 2.4 and above is  e.g. `/var/www/html/index.html` If you incorrectly modified `site-available` it will be operating against the original untouched version - until the next time the apache server is loaded - at which point it load in incorrect config and break

Comment: a new `site-available` config file is the right thing to do if you want to host mulitple domains on the same apache server e.g. `family.cf` **and** `family.com` but if you just have the one - just put files in root directory and leave config alone - trust me you dont want to break apache config, lol

Comment: if it returns blank its likely not accepting the config - maybe try without the `.`

Comment: right, - did not work so i tried again with the initial suggestion.  Although the name field is blank i can reach the webpage as long as i do not use www. before my domain name. If i typed 'mydomain.cf' in the browser it works though. I will try entering another field with www.mydomain.cf. > a record > myip to see if it works for the time being, but any suggestions would be great.

Comment: "a new site-available config file is the right thing to do if you want to host mulitple domains on the same apache server e.g. family.cf and family.com but if you just have the one - just put files in root directory and leave config alone"  right, i am with you now on that part. I will clean up that mess in the morning :D

Comment: yes - you are doing the right thing to make the `www.mydomain.cf` work. If that answered your basic question you can choose my answer by clicking the big tick mark